# style.opacity isn't working inside the ajax function

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have created a drag and drop feature on my website. When you put the image in this area, a preview of the image is shown along with the X mark on the upper right corner indicating remove the image. However, when I drop my image in this area, the X mark isn't becoming visible. The opacity isn't becoming 1.

Here is my code. The code is very long but I have picked the relevant portions: -

```
let deleteImage;

$(document).ready( function () {
    deleteImage = document.getElementById("deleteImage").addEventListener('click', removeImage);
})

function handleDrop(e) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        data = new FormData();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {  
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("Response " + this.responseText);
            imageUrlInput.value = this.responseText;
            previewDropArea.setAttribute("src", this.responseText ); 

            //------------- This code isn't working -----------------------------------
            deleteImage.style.opacity = "1";
        }
    }
}

let removeImage = function (event) {
    previewDropArea.setAttribute("src", "#");
    imageUrlInput.value = "";
    this.style.opacity = "0";
}
```

Here is my SASS associated with it: -

```
#deleteImage{
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        align-self: flex-start;
        position: relative;
        left: 90px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are setting `deleteImage` to the return value of `addEventListener(...)`, which doesn't return a value, and not to the actual element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `deleteImage` as the return value from `addEventListener`, so it isn't an HTML element.

You need to define `deleteImage` as the return value from `getElementById`.